# Pagination Missing

Tags: magento2, catalog, pagination

I am working with Magento2. Category pages seem to be not calling the Pagination at all.

I can see in toolbar.phtml

`<?php echo $block->getPagerHtml() ?>`

it is there correctly but doesn't show on the category page, and can't find the call needed for the XML in case this is the issue

To note, the category page has over 15 products and the Pagination doesn't display in the source

Comment: Make sure you did not installed Infinite Scroll module, because it is hide pagination.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add this method to your class if you haven't added yet. If you don't see it yet, you should debug this method. Don't forget to add your own _getProductCollection method with your collection, and setCollection() nethod.

```
/**
 * Retrieve Toolbar block
 *
 * @return \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar
 */
public function getToolbarBlock()
{
    $blockName = $this->getToolbarBlockName();
    if ($blockName) {
        $block = $this->getLayout()->getBlock($blockName);
        if ($block) {
            return $block;
        }
    }
    $block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock($this->_defaultToolbarBlock, uniqid(microtime()));
    return $block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pagination is display if product are greater than 9 by default setting.

By default pagination display in listing page at bottom left.

But if you want to display pagination at top you have to set display block property to `.toolbar-products .pages{display : block}` class in `styles-m.css`

Comment: As explained, it not showing at all, our toolbar is displaying correctly as part of it is showing and we have 15 products on the category

Comment: you have to check using inspect element and find .toolbar-products .pages class and check its visibility.

Comment: If I check the source code, the html for the pagination isn't there at all. Edit question to make this more clear.